# RecursionError with dataclasses default_factory

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

In my code I define a class using `dataclasses`, which has some lists of custom classes as attributes. Importing the file with this class throws a `ResursionError`, increasing the recursion limit to 100,000 did not help. Curiously this error does **not** occur when debugging the class definition (I am using PyCharm). This error did not occur, when I initialized some attributes as `None`. Now I use `dataclasses.field(default_factory=list)` on an attributed type hinted as a `list[MyDataClass]`. The reported error boils down to:

```
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/dataclasses.py", line 1176, in wrap
    return _process_class(cls, init, repr, eq, order, unsafe_hash,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/dataclasses.py", line 1094, in _process_class
    str(inspect.signature(cls)).replace(' -> None', ''))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/inspect.py", line 3204, in __str__
    formatted = str(param)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/inspect.py", line 2721, in __str__
    formatannotation(self._annotation))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/inspect.py", line 1361, in formatannotation
    return str(annotation)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/dataclasses.py", line 283, in __repr__
    return ('Field('
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/dataclasses.py", line 283, in __repr__
    return ('Field('
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/dataclasses.py", line 283, in __repr__
    return ('Field('
  [Previous line repeated 985 more times]
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

My class definitions do not allow for cyclical references as far as I am aware, though `MyDataClass` has a `classfunction` as a custom constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, the error was caused by an attribute having the same name as `MyDataClass`. Mea culpa, but I think I'll still file a bug report, if it hasn't been brought up yet.

EDIT: It has already been reported.